# Avoiding solitary walks because of demons?

Tags: halacha, three-weeks, sheidim-demons

In the Shulkhan Aruch, O''C 551:18 it is written:

> צריך ליזהר מי"ז בתמוז עד ט' באב שלא לילך יחידי מד' שעות עד ט' שעות (משום שבהם קטב מרירי שולט) ; ולא יכו התלמידים בימים ההם.‏
>
> From the Seventeenth of Tamuz until the Ninth of Av one needs to be careful not to walk alone from the fourth hour of the day until the ninth hour (because during these days [the demon] *ketev meriri* has control); and one should not beat students during those days.

Is this halakha of walking alone still applicable today? If rabbis have permitted people to walk alone during the three weeks, what is their reasoning?

Comment: Another question on the same passage: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29796

Comment: Anecdotally, when I was in day camp and we went hiking, we made sure to stay in pairs because of this concern

Comment: And related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2017/5323

Comment: werent the demons banished some time ago?

Answer (score 6):

[This](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/meaning-in-mitzvot/danger_during_the_three_weeks/) article by Rabbi Dr. Asher Meir of the Orthodox Union cites the same Shulkhan Aruch passage, and implicitly rules that it is still in effect.