# Discipline of children

Tags: children-parenting

When we have to administer a spanking to our seven year old, does Halakha demand an actual Rod? My husband and I use the palm of the hand on his bare behind.

Comment: Oy vey [15 char]

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Rifka.  You could start [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40195/4794) with this related and possibly duplicate question.

Answer (score 7):

Actually Halacha forbids a hard Rod. The discussion in [Hilchos Talmud Torah](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/13.htm) is a "retzua daka" - a thin strap - and **nothing** more, and if it doesn't work the first time, you don't try again.